# SQL - Trigger to update a column as NULL when another column has a fixed value

Tags: sql-server

I have a table for Seller. If seller type is 'organization', I want the MidName of Seller to be blank (NULL).
Is it possible to create a trigger that does so after insert?

Column names in table:

- SellerID
- Type(fixed value - either Org or Ind)
- FirstName
- MidName
- LastName
- Address
- PhoneNo

If `Type` is "Org" then `MidName` must be updated to blank (even if some value is entered during Insert)

Comment: Please provide table definition(s), the actual insert statement and expected results after insert.

Comment: How is the data getting into the database? If it's a stored procedure, you can check the values coming in and change the MidName before inserting the record.

Answer (score 4):

I agree with Andriy that a constraint should be used, but to answer your question if this is possible with a trigger, the answer is yes.

Here is the trigger:

```
CREATE TRIGGER i_Seller
ON Seller
AFTER INSERT
AS
IF EXISTS (SELECT NULL FROM inserted i WHERE Type = 'Org')
BEGIN;
    UPDATE s
    SET MidName = NULL
    FROM Seller s
    JOIN inserted i ON s.SellerID = i.SellerID
    WHERE s.Type = 'Org';
END;
```

Answer (score 2):

Not exactly an answer to the question as asked, but rather than having a trigger *reset* the `MidName` value, I would probably introduce a constraint to *prevent* the column from having a value:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.Seller
ADD CONSTRAINT CK_Seller_MidName
CHECK (MidName IS NULL OR Type = 'Ind');
                -- or: OR Type <> 'Org'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try something like this

```
CREATE TRIGGER ForceMidNameToNullOnTypeOrganizationAfterInsert ON Seller AFTER INSERT AS 
set nocount on;

UPDATE A 
    SET a.Midname=null
FROM 
    Seller a JOIN
    inserted b on
        b.SellerId=a.SellerId AND
        b.Type='Org' 
GO
```